# I need help with a Minecraft jukebox

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I like listening to music in Minecraft, so I was collecting music records from the creative menu. I put "blocks" into the jukebox, and no sound played. I waited, and nothing. I thought it might just be that one disc, so I tried listening to "cat" which I had heard earlier. Again, nothing happened. I tried turning up my jukebox/noteblock sound setting, but still nothing. I know it's not my computer, so what is it?!

Comment: Minecraft's sound engine a lot of times glitches out. Try restarting.

Answer (score 0):

I also used to have this problem in my survival but when I restarted the game and tried again it was working sftlr though and I hope it works

Answer (score -1):

I know you said you turned up the sound, but check one more time, make sure your main volume is also turned up. :)
Make sure your computer's sound is turned up too. Check your headphone jack to see if the sound is going into unused headphones also.
If none of that works, try restarting your minecraft window, and then your computer if that does not work. Good luck!